# Expo facebook authentication method or property is not on available on web

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to create a log in with facebook with Expo SDK 38 using the code for the login from the docs:

```
import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";

export async function signInWithFacebook() {

  try {
    await Facebook.initializeAsync("688582288586140");
    const {
      type,
      token,
      expires,
      permissions,
      declinedPermissions,
    } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
      permissions: ["public_profile"],
    });
    if (type === "success") {
      // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`
      );
      Alert.alert("Logged in!", `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }
  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

and i get the following error:

```
The method or property Facebook.initializeAsync is not available on web, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^38.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.2.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried re-installing all the dependencies, and i have also tried other versions of expo-facebook with no luck, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Auth for Expo web is not quite ready yet. You may keep track of the progress made here: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/6862

All we can do is wait for the pros to handle this feature for us. We can also contribute to open source of-course.

Answer (score 0):

i'm facing the same problem, but when i try to run this code at the redux reducer, if i run it at the component it works, have you tried Adding the values
`"facebookScheme": "", "facebookAppId": "", "facebookDisplayName": "",`
At the App.json, you can get those values at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios
At the step number 4